# Setting up admin panel in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, admin

In my project I am trying to create one section for admin. Following http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2009/07/Create-an-Admin-panel-with-CodeIgniter#top I tried the second method. According to it, my folder structure is changed to somewhat like this.

```
project
   cache
   config
   controllers
       -admin
          index.php
       -blog.php
   system
   views
       -admin
          index.php
        blog.php
...................
```

I have created one controller *index.php* inside *controllers/admin* with following code:

```
class Index extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view(index/index);
    }
}
```

And inside *views/admin* I have created a file *index.php* and echoed some string and in *routes.php* I have added this line,

```
$route['admin'] = 'admin/index';
```

But when I run the admin panel using the url, `http://localhost/workspace/project/admin/`, I am getting the 404 error

```
The requested URL /workspace/project/admin/ was not found on this server.
```

What I am doing wrong? Is there any other settings I have to make.

Can someone please guide me to fix this ? I am new to Codeigniter.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you try this url : **http://localhost/workspace/project/index.php/admin/** if it's work then please check your root .htaccess file.

Answer (score 1):

let change your files structure (You need to create an index function in your admin.php controller)

```
 project(may be root folder of CI)
    applications
       cache
       config
       controllers
           -admin
             index.php (method index)
           -blog.php
       system
       views
           -admin
              index.php
            blog.php
```

also change controller name to admin and view load

```
class Index extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('admin/index');
    }
}
```

then change your route

```
$route['admin'] = 'admin/index';
```

Comment: try $route['admin'] = 'admin/index/index';

Comment: try to access this url from browser is it working? and also i don't find applications dir in your struture

Comment: I tried with running localhost/workspace/project/index.php/admin and now 404 error has gone but it showing other error in page as "Use of undefined constant admin - assumed 'admin'" and " Use of undefined constant index - assumed 'index'" in file admin/index.php line 11

Comment: ok now check my updated answer create a controller in controller dir named admin and define method index in it

Comment: @Rakesh..before updating it I want the urls in admin section to be like http://project/admin/user, admin/language like that..so that I can create different controllers inside the admin section itself. How can I make out it using the updated method ?

Comment: you are all good may be default index controller not takin so try to create another controller in admin dir and check it

Comment: @Rakesh..I got it working the error was I missed putting single quotes in $this->load->view('admin/index');

Answer (score 1):

EDIT-
change routes to admin to this in routes.php

```
$route['admin/(:any)'] = "admin/$1";
```

Also, place this above your routes to default controller-

```
 $route['default_controller'] = "welcome";
    $route['404_override'] = '';
```

I hope it works!
////////////////////////////////////////////

I guess, something is wrong with your structure, If i am not wrong then its something like this-

```
project
   cache
   config
   controllers
       -admin   // your admin folder
          index.php   // your default controller
       -blog.php
   system
   views
       -admin
          index.php
        blog.php
```

change the controller name from index to admin.php
Hence the routes should be-

```
$route['admin'] = 'admin/admin/index'; // its like folder/controller/function
```

Comment: I tried this one. But not yet working. Is there any problem with the redirection in admin controller index()?

Comment: I guess not, ok lets try again, please wait, i am editing my asnwer!

Comment: @Sunny..I tried with the url localhost/workspace/project/index.php/admin and the 404 error has gone. But I am getting error in line $this->load->view(admin/index); in the controller

Comment: @jenz m sorry! i thought you were redirecting to controller.

Comment: @sunny..I got it working the error was I missed putting single quotes in $this->load->view('admin/index');

Comment: @Jenz Pleasure! and yes, routing can be a very delicate thinng in codeigniter, i recommend you to read this blog once about routing in CI http://blog.biernacki.ca/2011/12/codeigniter-uri-routing-issue-with-controller-folders/

Answer (score 0):

I prefer that you have 2 codeigniter projects one for admin and one for blog. As there would be common folders like images, css and js which would conflict.

There will also be salablility issues like common controller names as namespace in codeigniter is still a lengthy process to follow.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
class Index extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('admin/index');
    }
}
```

Comment: you provide wrong path to the view and put single quotes to them

Comment: The single qoutes does not make a difference in this instance.