# Codeigniter 3 controller in subfolder not working on live server

Tags: php, controller, codeigniter-3

I'm using CI 3.1.11

I got some problem when developed my app, which is I use CI. I try to create a new folder in `/app/controller/` on CI. Which one is `/Admin` to optimize my code.
So, my file looks like this :

```
--CONTROLLER
  --Admin
     Home.php
     User.php
  --Student
     Home.php
     Study.php
  Homepage.php
  Another.php
```

On local

```
http://localhost/myweb/admin/home
http://localhost/myweb/student/home
```

Its work.

BUT, when I try to host my site

```
http://sub.domain.com/admin/home
http://sub.domain.com/student/home
```

> Its broken not found page 404.

.
.
I test to set route.php on live server like :

```
$route['testpage'] = 'admin/home';
```

So I try,

```
http://sub.domain.com/testpage
```

Comment: Try with index.php http://sub.domain.com/index.php/testpage

Comment: Nope, its same error

Comment: I set index_page = " ";. Use htaccess

Comment: So you add .htaccess file in your main folder?

Comment: Uuuuhhhhh yes, doc pretty URL CI

Comment: ```RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]```

Comment: You can follow below processs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22828024/setting-up-admin-panel-in-codeigniter

Comment: I mean why when i set ```$route[testpage] = admin/home``` also ```$route[admin/(:any)] = "admin/$1" ``` its still not work

Comment: Its may mean a bug from CI? Or what another problem

Answer (score 0):

Been stuck with this issue for 2 days, and i found my solution as such :

if you have folder structure like below :

```
--CONTROLLER
  --Admin
     Home.php
     User.php
  --Student
     Home.php
     Study.php
  Homepage.php
  Another.php
```

you should define your routes in **routes.php** like this :

```
// for 'Admin' folder 
$route['testpage'] = "Admin/home";
$route['testpage/(:any)'] = "Admin/$1"; // to target Subfolder and other controller
$route['testpage/(:any)/(:any)'] = "Admin/$1/$2"; // to target controllers function
$route['testpage/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = "Admin/$1/$2/$3"; // to target controller function parameters
```

*Note that the folder name definition is capital letter (i think this is depend on server or php.ini configuration, not sure about it)*

in this case your subdomain will be :

```
http://sub.domain.com/testpage
```

I'm using **Codeigniter 3.1.11** with **PHP 7.3**